# How to compare AUCs using the boot package in R?

Tags: r, cross-validation, bootstrap

I would like to compare AUCs for two treatments using the boot package in R. However, something wrong with my R code and I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please give me a hint? many thanks in advance

```
require(boot)
#Create Data
set.seed(123)
N = 150
y1 = rnorm(150)
y2 = rnorm(150,1,0.2)
y3 = rnorm(150,2,0.5)
time = rep(1:3, each = 50)
trt = rep(rep(0:1, each = 25), times=3)
Data = data.frame(trt,time,y1,y2,y3)

#Trapezoid Rule
trap.rule = function(x,y) sum(diff(x)*(y[-1]+y[-length(y)]))/2

# Sum y1-y3 for each trt at each time point
SUM = function(data){
     set1 = subset(x = data, data$time==1)
     set2 = subset(x = data, data$time==2)
     set3 = subset(x = data, data$time==3)
     s1 = by(set1[,c("y1","y2","y3")], set1$trt, sum)
     s2 = by(set1[,c("y1","y2","y3")], set2$trt, sum)
     s3 = by(set3[,c("y1","y2","y3")], set3$trt, sum)
     result = matrix(data = c(s1[1],s2[1],s3[1],
                              s1[2],s2[2],s3[2]), ncol=2)
     colnames(result) = c("trt = 0", "trt = 1")
     output = cbind(time = 1:3,result)
     return(output)
}

# Statistic for boot
AREA = function(data,i){
        d = data[i,]
        MQ = SUM(data = d)
        A.0 = trap.rule(x = 1:3, y = MQ[,2])
        A.1 = trap.rule(x = 1:3, y = MQ[,3])
        area = A.1 - A.0
        result = c(A.0, A.1, area)
        return(result)
}

area.boot = boot(data = Data, statistic = AREA, R = 1000)
area.boot
```

However, there is an error message

```
Error in tapply(1L:49L, list(`set2$trt` = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,  : 
  arguments must have same length
```

Comment: The problem is in your function AREA.

Comment: Hi Pocrastinator, I have a typo in my SUM function (see Daniel's comment). That's why boot can't work with AREA function. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm just getting started with R... Shouldn't it be set2 in the s2 assignment:

```
 s1 = by(set1[,c("y1","y2","y3")], set1$trt, sum)
 s2 = by(set2[,c("y1","y2","y3")], set2$trt, sum)
 s3 = by(set3[,c("y1","y2","y3")], set3$trt, sum)
```